# CSS: How to center the snackbar horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I am using a simple snackbar code from w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_snackbar). It works OK but for long message it starts to move off the horizontal center, for example.

```
<div id="snackbar">Some very very very very very very long text some message..</div>
```

I try to fix it by removing "margin-left" and also "left", and only setting `"margin: 0 auto"` but it doesn't work.

Comment: text-align:center ? or width:max-content ?  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GC2BZEKELMD1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `margin-left: -125px;`
and add: `transform: translateX(-50%);` 
from #snackbar selector.

Answer (score 1):

In that example, the snackbar is positioned fixed at 50% and re-positioned with a negative margin of 125px - and that's the problem. Those 125px are a so called 'magical number', i.e. a number that only works in special circumstances. In this case, it only works for a special width of the snackbar. It fails in any other width. Bad! ;)

It would be better to position (as it is done in the example) at 50%, but then (other than in the example) re-position it by half of its own width. You can do so with

```
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Those 50% refer to the width of the snackbox itself.

EDIT: Wooops, Lazar Delic was way faster! :)

Answer (score 0):

I placed snackbar inside a flex container to place it in center. You can read more about flexbox layout from this article: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.snackbar-root {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.snackbar {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="snackbar-root">
  <div class="snackbar">Here goes short message</div>
  <div class="snackbar">Here goes some loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong messsssssssssssssssssssage</div>
</div>
```